# posterous api request with jquery only

Tags: jquery, ajax, posterous

I  am trying to use jquery to interact with posterous api , however I am unable to make sense of url and how parameters will be passed . I am using this :

$.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url : 'http://posterous.com/api/2/users/me/sites',
                        dataType:'xml',
                        success: function(data,textStatus){
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert('XHR : ' + xhr.status);
                            alert("Error:"+thrownError);
                        }

});
                    });

I am sure I will have to authenticate myself to access the sites , but posterous api has'nt given any examples on how to do that , does any one have idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If they use Basic Auth you will need to provide a username and password (usually login and email respectively)

Look at the username and password arguments you can configure in the ajax call:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: herbert penito

I tried this approach , but everytime I am getting XHR status of 0 when I send the request

Answer (score 0):

you need to include an authorized token with every request. see this website to see how to get the token http://apidocs.posterous.com/pages/authentication then include the data property with your ajax call `data:{api_token:YOUR_TOKEN}`

Comment: crossman
Maybe i am  wrong in jquery then , because everytime I am getting xhr : 0

`code`
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
     
     
     $("a").click(function(){
     
     $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url : 'http://posterous.com/api/2/auth/token',
      dataType:'xml',
      success: function(data,textStatus){
       alert(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       alert('XHR : ' + xhr.status);
       alert("Error:"+thrownError);
      }
     
     
});
     });
      
    
});

</script>

<a href="">Click on link</a>
`code`

Comment: your dataType is set to XML the posterous api only returns JSON data for now.. try changing this to JSON and let me know